# sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout: How to set default section page on load?

Tags: sapui5

I am using the `sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout` with a bunch of `ObjectPageSection`s. I would like to have the first section being displayed whenever I open the view containing the ObjectPageLayout. I have seen that there is [association](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout/associations) `selectedSection` but it needs a value of type `sap.uxap.ObjectPageSection`. Settings the ID of the first section does not help. So what am I supposed to enter there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll need to set it when you enter the route again of your ObjectPageLayout. Then `this.byId("objectPageLayout").setSelectedSection(this.byId("sectionId"))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ID of the section in the XMLView as well, despite the [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout) saying that the association awaits an object of type `sap.uxap.ObjectPageSection`.

```xml
<uxap:ObjectPageLayout selectedSection="firstSection">
  <uxap:ObjectPageSection id="firstSection">
```

> **selectedSection:** The section that is selected by default on load.